# Get value of label changed by jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a label in my asp page.

```
<asp:Label runat="server" style="display: block;" ID="lblRegistrationNo" cssClass="lblUprsregNo"> </asp:Label>
```

it is populated by a jquery function. but I am unable to get this value on server side.

```
protected void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string regNo = lblRegistrationNo.Text;
}
```

it always **returns an empty string**.

Comment: it will take javascript change in code end. You have to get Data by Other Way

Comment: Use `hidden field` and set the value of label in your Jquery function. In your code behind you can access the field using `Request.Forms["hiddenfieldname"]`

Comment: I am setting the value of label in my jquery function. should I also set the value of hidden field from that jquery function?

Comment: On the serverSide you can **only get values SENT from your client to the server**. As labels are not sent *(except anything in the viewState)* to the server, you won't have a chance to get this value. Set the value to a formField too and you will have access to it on the server side!

Comment: Yes I got that value from hidden Field. Thank you @Pilgerstorfer Franz.

Comment: I think @yash would appreciate an upvote and/or selecting the answer as best one. glad we could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a HiddenField with label also. And Set Value of hidden Field same as Label. You can Access hiddenField value in back End.